# How to restore a virtual system after accidentally removing all kernels?

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I have seen answers for actual installs but am not sure this would work for Virtual.

Like a fool, I had not backed up the data on a VM I used at work.  When I tried to upgrade I was out of space and like a bigger fool, wiped out all kernels instead of just old ones when trying to free up space.  Now I boot into Memtest86 and can go no further because grub(?) sees no other kernel.

The VM was Ubuntu 14.04 running in Oracle VM VirtualBox. Is there a way to mount the image from another Ubuntu VM and reinstall the kernel? The directory has an Ubuntu.vbox file and a Ubuntu.vdi file as well as a Ubuntu.vbox.prev file that seems to just be XML data

---

UPDATE:
Mounted from desktop in "Try Ubuntu" mode, chrooted in to `/media/ubuntu/<diskname>` and had to manually override to write a new `/etc/resolv.conf`. 
When I did the `apt-get install linux-image-generic` it seemed to have write issues. Did I mount incorrectly?

I mounted just by selecting the HD listed in "Files" and after

```
sudo chroot /media/ubuntu/<diskname>
```

I confirmed that the existing users were listed in /home/ so I am pretty sure I was on the right drive, but when I tried to mount it the way other how-to show, I get:

```
sudo mount /media/ubuntu/<long HD name>
mount: /media/ubuntu/<long HD name> is not a block device
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70060/discussion-on-question-by-gwalker-how-to-restore-a-virtual-system-after-accident).

Comment: The above was done at one of the commentor's requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem very easily, so go through the steps below one by one:

1. Insert a Live CD ISO image into the Virtualbox disk drive.
2. Change the boot order for the Virtualbox drives to boot from this ISO image and boot into it.
3. choose 'Try Ubuntu' and open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
4. Run `lsblk` to find the proper device name for your VM main drive.
5. Mount the drive into `/mnt` where `XX` is the proper drive label for the drive you want to rescue:

   ```bash
   mount /dev/sdXX /mnt
   ```
6. Now mount and bind the following to make a proper install possible:

   ```bash
   sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
   sudo mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
   sudo mount -t sysfs /sys /mnt/sys
   sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
   sudo cp /proc/mounts /mnt/etc/mtab
   sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
   ```
7. Chroot into the mountpoint with `sudo chroot /mnt`.
8. Run an update of the packet-lists:

   ```bash
   apt-get update
   # you might want to do an upgrade as well if you like
   apt-get upgrade
   ```
9. Now you can install the kernel again with:

   ```bash
   apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic
   ```
10. Run `update-grub` to make sure grub points again to a working installed kernel.
11. Now you can exit the chroot environment by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and wrap up before you shut down the VM and reboot it on the normal drive:

    ```bash
    sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts
    sudo umount /mnt/dev
    sudo umount /mnt/sys
    sudo umount /mnt/proc
    sudo umount /mnt
    ```

This should have done it and your VM now again has a kernel to boot from

Comment: Worked! Many thanks for your patience and help!